# The Relationship between Chrome DevTools Protocol and Google Browser Version

Tags: cdp

When using Chrome 104 and below, obtain the http://127.0.0.1:9222/json After the webSocketDebuggerUrl link in, it is possible to make a ws connection. But when it comes to Chrome 114 version, ws is invalid. May I ask why? thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hn8v.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msls0.png)

I would like to know the relationship between the Chrome DevTools Protocol and the Chrome version

Comment: How can I connect to a browser through websocket when starting Chrome from the command line in version 114 of Chrome?
When the Chrome version is 102, communication can be done through websocket.

Comment: Why can't I directly connect to Chrome 114 through websocket without using a puppeteer